# How to give permission to applications in order to make changes on mounted partition

Tags: partitioning, sudo

I use dual operating systems: Ubuntu and Windows 7.

I want to share on both Ubuntu and Windows only one Dropbox folder.

Whenever my computer starts, It mounts automatically an ntfs partition which contains my Dropbox folder.

I make it with that line in `/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/sda3 /media/Phobos ntfs rw,defaults,users,umask=007,gid=46,noatime   0  0
```

#### The problem is that

If any file in Dropbox changes (not by me), I take a permission violated error. Dropbox cannot synchronize. Although I can write a file in Dropbox folder or another folder on Phobos, applications that I start, cannot.

If I make:

```
sudo dropbox start
```

Dropbox can synchronize. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I don't use dropbox but the way you described this it sounds like dropbox isn't actually starting at boot-up.  Have you verified that dropbox is being handled by rc.d?  Perhaps you need to update-rc.d dropbox defaults (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto)

Comment: I haven't problem with dropbox only, `tar` isn't working by the same reason. `tar` start extract but files cannot be written on this disk.
Ubuntu starts dropbox for every boot-up if what you asked.